# Splitting record set in Rails for display purposes in menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to split my records in half for display in my menu. The menu is two columns (col-md-4) but the methods I'm using with **ODD** number of records, puts the larger number on the wrong side (last_half) of my menu. What am I missing?

**Menu**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul>
    <li class="mega-menu-title">Products</li>
    <% first_half(@menu_products).each do |product| %>
      <li>
        <%= link_to product_path(product) do %>
          <span class="text-yellow"><%= product.name %></span> <%= product.subtitle %>
        <% end %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul>
    <li class="mega-menu-title">&nbsp;</li>
    <% last_half(@menu_products).each do |product| %>
      <li>
        <%= link_to product_path(product) do %>
          <span class="text-yellow"><%= product.name %></span> <%= product.subtitle %>
        <% end %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <!--- non-related code in last column in menu --->
</div>
```

**Application Helper**

```
def first_half(list)
  list[0...(list.length / 2)]
end

def last_half(list)
  list[(list.length / 2)...list.length]
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing to get it to work. I had to change the length to a float `to_f`, then I could get it to test in the console correctly.

```
def first_half(list)
  list[0...(list.length.to_f / 2).ceil]
end

def last_half(list)
  list[(list.length.to_f / 2).ceil...list.length]
end
```

Using `.ceil` on both methods then allowed the math to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
list.first((list.length/2).ceil) # will convert 1.5 to 2
```

And

```
list.last((list.length/2).floor) # will convert 1.5 to 1
```

---

The issue you had is that `[7,8,9][3/2]` returns `8`, and the logic `3/2` (`list.size / 2`) was used in both `first_half` and `last_half`.

Comment: Your solution didn't exactly work for me but got me on the right track. I was using `ceil` and `floor` in testing but it never gave be the split I needed. Please see my solution below using `to_f`.